# How would I use Yeoman or other dev tools on a ChromeBook?

Tags: chromebook

If I want to use http://yeoman.io/ or other commandline dev and build tools on a ChromeBook, what's the simplest way to do so that works EXACTLY like a regular Linux environment (i.e. Ubuntu)?

...
Alternatively, are there any online services that essentially let me interact with commandline tools (running on a virtual Linux machine somewhere out there) via the browser, but without me actually having to manage a virtual machine myself?

Comment: You can put the device into developer mode and access the more full-featured shell. Im not sure if that would work for Yeoman but you essentially get a full linux shell

Answer (score 0):

The Chromebook ships with a limited shell.  Developer mode unlocks a slightly better one, but still doesn't give you the ability to install things (that I've found anyway).  So I'm gonna advocate for [crouton](https://github.com/dnschneid/crouton) here.  It will let you install a full-blown desktop environment, but if you only want command line it works for that too.

These steps will let you run command-line Ubuntu in a Chrome tab:

- put the chromebook into [dev mode](https://sites.google.com/site/chromeoswikisite/home/what-s-new-in-dev-and-beta/developer-mode)
- download crouton
- open a shell with `ctrl alt t`
- type `shell` to access the better shell
- `cd` into the directory you put crouton into and install Ubuntu using: `sudo sh -e crouton -t cli-extra` (this uses the `cli-extra` target available via crouton, and it's just basic command line Ubuntu, no X, no desktop, etc.)

Now, you have a command-line-only Ubuntu distro installed.  To use it:

- open a shell like before with `ctrl alt t`
- get into the better shell with `shell`
- open the crouton'd chroot using `sudo enter-chroot`

I did exactly these steps over the summer to do some light C++ work, and it was just so cool to have a whole other OS "inside" a Chrome tab.